# wsprintf and empty string for %s

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2013, printf

In VS13 I have this code:

```
wstring Result, EmptyString{ L"" };
if( EmptyString == L"" )
    Result = wstrprintf( L">%s<", L"" );
Result = wstrprintf( L">%s<", EmptyString );
```

The first wsprintf correctly returns `><` but the second returns `>☐+<` where the two middle characters are random wchars. I see no reason why.

Is there an alternative?

Comment: `I see no reason why`  1) The `wstrprintf` function knows nothing about `std::wstring`.  2) it is undefined behavior to pass the wrong type to `wstrprintf` (the type doesn't match the format argument).  3) it is undefined behavior to use a non-POD type in a variable argument function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` requires a C string: `EmptyString.c_str()`, not a `std::wstring` object.